# How do I remove "Read your mail" consent from Azure AD login panel?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a web app which uses Azure AD as the identity platform for managing users, login etc.

This is my consent panel at the moment when a new user wants to login:

[image]

How do I remove the "Read your mail" consent?
I don't want my app to have access to users email.

Thanks

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify permission that you granted to your application,  just go to Azure Portal=> Azure Active Directory => App registrations => select your application => API permissions to remove the permission,just as below:
[image]